# Any other mathematicians like Galois in recent history?

Tags: soft-question, galois-theory, mathematicians

Any other mathematicians like Galois in recent history ?

For "someone like Galois", I mean someone who developed a completely new theory all by himself, solved a big problem and the theory has big impact.

(maybe one more condition, before he made this big discovery, he did not belong to mainstream math community).

Anyone like this in recent history ?

Comment: Alexander Grothendieck and Jacob Lurie come to mind.

Comment: Needs to be Community Wiki. However, it's an awfully broad question. Should it be closed?

Comment: Galois was not part of "mainstream math" as he was a teen when he did all that stuff. Nowadays, everything's so complex that it's almost impossible for anyone to do something original, never mind "developing a completely new theory", before he/she is a graduate student, and in some fields, a working professor.